# How can Boost be used to achieve C++14-style auto return types?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

Suppose I have a function that adds two values together. If I know nothing about the types then I basically have to write my function twice; once in the actual return value and again as the return type specifier:

```
template <typename A, typename B>
auto Add(const A& a, const B& b) ->std::decay<decltype(a + b)>::type
{
  return a + b;
}
```

While this works, it is undesirable because it is difficult to read and difficult to maintain.

In C++14 this won't be an issue, because we can drop the return type specifier (I am not sure it'll do the decay though...). For now, I'm stuck with C++11.

It has been my experience that whenever I am seeking a feature in C++ that hasn't yet made its way into the standard, but for which there is an obvious need, the [Boost library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boost_%28C%2B%2B_libraries%29) usually has a solution. I have searched through the documentation, but I haven't found anything that might help me. The `BOOST_AUTO_RETURN` and `BOOST_TYPEOF_TPL` features seem more aimed at providing C++11 functionality to C++03 users.

Basically what I'm after is something that performs the following functionality:

```
template <typename A, typename B>
auto Add(const A& a, const B& b)
{
  return a + b; // Deduce return type from this, like C++14 would
}
```

Is there some functionality in the Boost library that I'm unaware of (or a nifty trick in C++11) that might allow me to forego the explicit `-> decltype(...)` after every auto return type? How would this be implemented?

Comment: Those marking this as off-topic should really review the guidelines: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic This is a question about a specific, reproducible problem with sufficient information to diagnose. It is not homework and it is not asking for recommendations.

Comment: I'm not sure why the question was down-voted. I'm not aware of a way to avoid the decltype(<expression>) syntax

Comment: Well, if you're not asking for recommendations then it isn't clear what you're asking for. How is this a problem you're trying to solve with your own code?

Comment: @CareyGregory I've written what I'm asking in the title, then I proceed to show you what I've done, and then I write what I think a solution might look like. I am not asking anyone to recommend anything, I'm asking for a solution to a problem. If you think I could be clearer on this please let me know.

Comment: I think the problem is that your actual question is: "Does this exist?" Well, I don't know, does it? Are you asking us to go search the Boost documentation for you? If not, then what are you asking us to do?

Comment: @CareyGregory Like I said, I think you should review the guidelines. Asking if something can be done does not make it off topic.

Comment: You aren't asking if it can be done, and if you were that would be asking for opinions.

Comment: I don't know what that means.

Comment: If the question is "is there something in Boost that does this?", you should go search the Boost documentation. If the question is "can I write a macro `BOOST_AUTO_RETURN` such that `BOOST_AUTO_RETURN f()`automagically performs return type deduction in a C++11 compiler?", the answer is likely no. If the question is "can I write a macro that saves me from typing the trailing return type?", the answer is likely yes (with a function-like macro), but the resulting code would be quite ugly.

Comment: You might be able to use [`Boost.Typeof`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/typeof/tuto.html). [Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6b32aec69ea1d396).

Comment: Syntax-wise, `BOOST_TYPEOF_TPL` is like `decltype`, so it doesn't save you from typing anything.

Comment: I disagree. "Is there something in Boost?" is a "Find off-site resource" question. The reason why C++14 introduced this feature is because it was a bitch in C++11. There are no answers to this question that are not "Go search the Boost docs".

Comment: @Puppy: just because something exists in the documentation it does not mean that it is obviously related to the problem or straightforward to use, especially to someone inexperienced. If that was true then SO should shut down because everything is documented *somewhere*...

Comment: @Puppy There is no question on this website that couldn't be answered by telling someone to "go and read *something*", but that doesn't make such an answer helpful or productive, nor does it mean the original question was somehow invalid. I still do not understand why this has been so controversial.

Comment: There is a difference between "How do I do *x* under *y* circumstances?" and "Please refer me to an off-site resource." That difference should be quite obvious. The former is perfectly on-topic here, the latter is not. Do note that many questions that ostensibly fall into the latter category can be rephrased to fall into the former category. There is a lesson there: if you want to know how to do something, *ask how to do it*, not indirectly for a guide somewhere that tells you how to do it. Answerers are free to link to those resources in their answers if they wish and think appropriate.

Comment: @Puppy, maybe we'll just have to disagree on this. I don't think it's a fair expectation of the community that its members have read the entire documentation of a given standard to which the question pertains. I would love to have read and know the entire `boost` documentation, but unfortunately I don't. Any question pertaining to boost could be answered by a lexical knowledge of the documentation, that doesn't make such a question unreasonable.

Comment: @CodyGray That's helpful. Thanks. I've definitely learnt a lesson here about phrasing questions. This question might have been better received if I had left `boost` out of the post altogether.

Comment: I'm glad it was helpful. But you don't necessarily have to leave Boost out of the picture. If you don't want to use Boost, that's a constraint you need to mention. If you would *like* to use Boost, then you might ask the question then say at the bottom, "Is this possible using Boost? I checked the documentation, but I didn't see anything that looked related." That kills two birds with one stone—it shows people that you tried researching and solving the problem yourself first before asking (which is appreciated), and it gets out there that you'd like to use Boost if possible.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The only possible deduced function return type in C++11 is the return type of a lambda. C++11 restricts the use of lambdas, though. This works:

```
auto add = [](int a, int b) { return a + b; };
```

This is valid, and defines `add` as a lambda that defines an `operator()` member function that returns `int`. Since the lambda doesn't capture anything, you can even write

```
auto add = +[](int a, int b) { return a + b; };
```

to make `add` a regular pointer-to-function: it gets type `int(*)(int, int)`.

However, C++11 doesn't allow parameter types to be specified as `auto`, nor to let `add` be defined as a template variable, so you cannot use this to generically deduce a return type. An attempt to wrap it up in a template class fails:

```
template <typename A, typename B>
struct S { static auto add = [](A a, B b) { return a + b; }; }; // invalid
```

It is invalid to initialise `add` in-class here, and you cannot use `auto` unless the member is initialised in-class. Besides, even if it did work, it wouldn't allow deduction of `A` or `B`, which seems to be more what you're after.

Given those limitations, I don't see any alternative but to repeat the expression. You could hide the repetition in a trivial macro, though.

```
#define AUTO_RETURN(func, ...) auto func -> decltype(__VA_ARGS__) { return __VA_ARGS__; }

template <typename A, typename B>
AUTO_RETURN(add(A a, B b), a + b)
```

Or the variant pointed out by Marc Glisse,

```
#define RETURNS(...) noexcept(noexcept(__VA_ARGS__)) -> decltype(__VA_ARGS__) { return __VA_ARGS__; }

template <typename A, typename B>
auto add(A a, B b) RETURNS(a + b)
```

which looks a bit cleaner.

There might be something like this in Boost already, I don't know. Regardless, given the triviality, Boost seems overkill here.

Comment: The macro is the usual solution (you can also add noexcept for a third use of the body), though usually func is kept outside the macro, so it would look like `add(A a, B b) RETURNS(a+b)`

Comment: @MarcGlisse To be complete, it would look like `auto add(A a, B b) RETURNS(a+b)`, and I wanted `auto` to be part of the macro expansion result. Looking at your form now, though, I do think that looks much better, so I've edited it in. Thanks!

Comment: Boost is never overkill

Comment: @bamboon Boost is useful, but unless it's changed in recent versions, it has versioning problems where linking multiple projects together that all pull in Boost, and don't use the same version, causes big problems, and where Boost was not backwards-compatible enough to trust that compiling all projects with the same version wouldn't break any of the projects. So I'm hesitant to use Boost, if I don't have a good reason for doing so.

Comment: Note that this is an emulation of the C++14 `decltype(auto)`, not plain `auto` like the OP was asking, but it is trivial to make 2 versions of the macro where one uses `decay`. Also, this emulation actually has some advantages compared to the C++14 syntax in that it allows SFINAE.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Fair point, but the OP already knows of `std::decay` and has used it in the question, so I am confident that it won't be a problem. I left it out to keep my answer simpler, and because `auto` has the option to do less than `std::decay` does, so unconditionally using `std::decay` probably isn't right either. (Think `auto&`, for instance.)

Comment: I often leave the `->` out of the `RETURNS` for `auto add(A a, B b)->RETURNS(a+b)` which I find pretty.  But it does cost `noexcept`.

Comment: I noticed that `sfinae` check on expression in trailing return type could lead to negative results too, with using complex patterns like CRTP. I'm trying to reproduce `decltype(auto)` for gcc 4.8 and since function may return both values and references, returning `auto&` isn't helping either.

Answer (score 5):

There is a library [Pythy](https://github.com/pfultz2/Pythy) that tries emulate this syntax. However, it will only work on clang. It doesn't work on gcc due to these bugs [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55159) and [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55003). They may be fixed for gcc 4.9, but if you are using gcc 4.9 you can use auto return types, anyways.

Comment: Both bugs linked are marked as fixed in 4.8, is that wrong?

Comment: The error I'm getting with GCC 4.8.3 is [reported here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59975), it's not one of the two you link to. The error I'm getting with clang 3.4.2 is a hard "a lambda expression may not appear inside of a constant expression", which seems rather explicit in that this is just not going to work, at least not with that version of clang.

Comment: By the way, I had included some comments here that suggest that the code is meant to be invalid, but my reasoning was incorrect, so I've deleted them. I have no idea if anything like your answer is meant to be valid. It's a neat trick regardless.